# Why is the release of season 2 of Attack on Titan delayed?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The first season of *Attack on Titan* **aired from April 6, 2013 to September 28, 2013**, as stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan). Although the anime is popular and there are demands for the second season, the second season is not yet released. I came across [this article](http://www.latintimes.com/attack-titan-season-2-release-date-news-director-talks-delays-plot-plus-5-other-323275), which explains the reason for the delay as:

> According to the director, there are a lot of things happening in the "Attack on Titan" franchise this year, which hinders the second season production and has delayed the hit-anime to 2016. It was also revealed the delay is due to Hajime Isayama's best-selling manga lacking two-story arc, which make it impossible for Araki to come up with a new season.

This makes fans (like me of course) impatient... What is this **lacking two-story arc** referring to?

Comment: A similar article on earlier date in Jun 2015: http://www.christiantoday.com/article/attack.on.titan.director.talks.s2.delays.rumored.plot.discussed/55201.htm. However, the news of the 2nd season has been announced since Nov 2014. http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-11-21/attack-on-titan-tv-anime-gets-2nd-season-in-2016/.81305 I guess the author of those articles has access to the event video (probably from the BD/DVD? of the movies) and wrote based on that information?

Comment: I have watched [the video of the announcement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9Ex7nf2XEg), and there is no comment from the director about the delay. [Other videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/maidigitv/search?query=%E5%8A%87%E5%A0%B4%E7%89%88%E3%80%8E%E9%80%B2%E6%92%83%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%A8%E4%BA%BA%E3%80%8F+) on the channel, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this lacking two-story arc referring to?

I recall reading that and I believe it should have read "lacking **a** two-story arc", meaning there either wasn't enough material in the manga for the anime creators to do a second season, or the material present hadn't yet concluded any identifiable second "arc".